# Sorting a list of collections performance tips

Tags: java, list, performance, collections

I have a list of collections that contains pairs, I should keep the list sorted alphabetically by it's collections pairs key, My current solution is keeping the list sorted by overriding the add method, Like the code below.

Note: the list collections pairs key are always the same like

(Car,1)(Car,1)

(Bear,1)

So i just need to get first pair key of collections to get it sorting the list

```
List<Collection<Pair<String, Integer>>> shufflingResult;

public void init() {
    shufflingResult = new ArrayList<>() {
        public boolean add(Collection<Pair<String, Integer>> c) {
            super.add(c);
            Collections.sort(shufflingResult, new Comparator<Collection<Pair<String, Integer>>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Collection<Pair<String, Integer>> pairs, Collection<Pair<String, Integer>> t1) {
                    return pairs.iterator().next().getKey().compareTo(t1.iterator().next().toString());
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Is this the best performance way to do what i'm looking for?

Comment: should probably be on code review stack

Answer (score -1):

If the collection is already sorted and all you want to do is add.  do a binary search and then just use `list.add(index,element);` sorting every time you want to insert is bad.  you should do it once and then just maintain with good insertion order.

adding some code to show the bsearch. as the one for collections will only return matches. just supply the list. the new object. and the comparator that sorts the list how you want it. if adding many items where N> current size of the list probably better to add all then sort.

```
private static void add(List<ThingObject> l, ThingObject t, Comparator<ThingObject> c) {
    if (l != null) {
        if (l.size() == 0) {
            l.add(t);
        } else {
            int index = bSearch(l, t, c);
            l.add(index, t);
        }
    }
}

private static int bSearch(List<ThingObject> l, ThingObject t, Comparator<ThingObject> c) {
    boolean notFound = true;
    int high = l.size() - 1;
    int low = 0;
    int look = (low + high) / 2;
    while (notFound) {
        if (c.compare(l.get(look), t) > 0) {
            // it's to the left of look
            if (look == 0 || c.compare(l.get(look - 1), t) < 0) {
                //is it adjacent?
                notFound = false;
            } else {
                //look again.
                high = look - 1;
                look = (low + high) / 2;
            }
        } else if (c.compare(l.get(look), t) < 0) {
            // it's to the right of look
            if (look == l.size() - 1 || c.compare(l.get(look + 1), t) > 0) {
                //is it adjacent?
                look = look + 1;
                notFound = false;
            } else {
                //look again.
                low = look + 1;
                look = (low + high) / 2;
            }
        } else {
            notFound = false;
        }

    }
    return look;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Performance is a tricky thing. The best sort algorithm will depend largely on the volume and type of data, and to what degree it is random. Some algorithms are best when Data which is partially sorted, others for truly random data.

Generally speaking, worry about optimization until you've determined that working code is not sufficiently performant. Get things working first, and then determine where the bottleneck it. It may not be sorting, but something else.

Java provides good general sorting algorithms. You're using one with Collections.sort(). There is no SortedList in Java, [but javafx.base contains a SortedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html) which wraps a supplied List and keeps is sorted based on a Comparator supplied at instantiation. This would prevent you from having to override the base behavior of the List implementation.

While your code seems like it may work, here's a couple of suggestions:

1. pairs.iterator().next().getKey() will throw an NPE if pairs is null.
2. pairs.iterator().next().getKey() will throw an NoSuchElementException if pairs is empty.
3. pairs.iterator().next().getKey() will throw an NPE if the first Pair has a null key is empty.
4. All of this is true for t1 as well.
5. You're comparing pairs.iterator().next().getKey() to t1.iterator().next().toString(). One is the String representation of the Pair, and the other is the Key from the Pair. Is this correct?

While your code may make sure these conditions never happen, someone may modify it later with resulting unpleasant surprises. You may want to add validations to your add method to ensure that these cases won't occur. Throwing IllegalArgumentException when arguments aren't valid is generally good practice.

Another thought: Since your Collection contents are always the same, and if no two Collections have the same kind of Pairs, you should be able to  use a SortedMap<String, Collection<Pair<String,Integer>>> instead of a List. If you are comparing by Key this sort of Map will keep things sorted for you. You'll `put` the Collection using the first Pair's Key as the map/entry key. The map's `keySet()`, `values()` and `entrySet()` will all return Collections which iterate in sorted order.

Comment: Java is going to sort the way it's going to sort. this has nothing to do with the performance of the operation in question. Using SortedList is a good mention and probably a good option. but not mentioning that just sorting every time is bad is missing a lot.

Comment: The default search algorithm for Arrays.sort() (which is what Collections.sort() calls) is the DualPivotQuickSort. This version of Quicksort doesn't degrade as badly as QuickSort in many cases and is generally more performant. Both Quicksort and Binary Search have O(n log(n)) performance.

Java sorts just fine.

How large is the List (Collection sizes aren't relevant)? If they are small, InsertionSort will outperform MergeSort, QuickSort etc, especially on partially/largely sorted collections, which you will have if you sort on each insert.

Comment: binary search is log(n) not nLog(n) hence why it's so much better if it's already sorted.

Comment: `Generally speaking, worry about optimization until you've determined that working code is not sufficiently performant.` why would you worry only up until the point where it becomes terrible. seems like that is the time to be most concerned.

Comment: AFAIK DualPivotQuickSort gets only used for primitives. For objects, Java guarantees stable sorting, which precludes QuickSort . Instead, TimSort gets used, which handles well already mostly sorted sequences. This is useful in the OP's case as the complexity of their `add` is `O(n)` rather than `O(n * log(n))`.